# PHP: How to split a string by dash and everything between brackets. (preg_split or preg_match)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-split

I've been wrapping my head around this for days now, but nothing seems to give the desired result.

Example:

```
$var = "Some Words - Other Words (More Words) Dash-Binded-Word";
```

Desired result:

```
array(
[0] => Some Words
[1] => Other Words
[2] => More Words
[3] => Dash-Bound-Word
)
```

I was able to get this all working using preg_match_all, but then the "Dash-Bound-Word" was broken up as well. Trying to match it with surrounding spaces didn't work as it would break all the words except the dash bound ones.

The preg_match_all statement I used (which broke up the dash bound words too) is this:

```
preg_match_all('#\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]|[^?!\-|\(|\[]+#', $var, $array);
```

I'm certainly no expert on preg_match, preg_split so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `explode()` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php ?

Comment: Nevermind. Explode may not work the way you want it in this case.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I tried explode() before starting with preg_match_all, and although I was able to explode the dashes, I didn't get it to work for parts that are between the brackets. :( Thank you for the tip though. If you know a way to get it working via that way that would be awesome.

Comment: See my answer below and see if it helps. It will work for this case but you might have to make changes if you plan to use it for other cases too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple `preg_match_all`:

```
\w+(?:[- ]\w+)*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV3mP1/1)

- `\w+` - 1 or more alphanumeric or underscore
- `(?:[- ]\w+)*` - 0 or more sequences of...

  - `[- ]` - a hyphen or space (you may change space to `\s` to match any whitespace)
  - `\w+` - 1 or more alphanumeric or underscore

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/rpKbBd):

```
$re = '/\w+(?:[- ]\w+)*/'; 
$str = "Some Words - Other Words (More Words) Dash-Binded-Word"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Some Words
    [1] => Other Words
    [2] => More Words
    [3] => Dash-Binded-Word
)
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it was the cleanest and shortest solution of all answers. It solved my exact question, not leaving any unnecessary whitespace or empty array values. Thanks a lot for your help! :D

Comment: Nice approach!. Allow me to point out this would fail in cases where a string has multiple spaces between words, or chars not matched by `\w+`, such as `Some    Words - Other! Words` (notice multiple spaces are not shown in a comment).

Comment: If I were to capture the brackets, but not capture the dash, would that be possible using a slightly tweaked version of this regex? I just realized I sometimes need to know if the words were between brackets.

Comment: To capture optional brackets: `(\(?)\w+(?:[- ]\w+)*(\)?)` (and check the group 1 and 2).

Comment: Okay, so I can use `(\(?)\w+(?:[- ]+\w+)*(\)?)` in the preg_split to determine which of the values has brackets and then add them again? Thank you for taking the time to help me out, although this wasn't in the original question.

Comment: I think I got it, never mind! Thank you for your extensive help.

Comment: As for multiple spaces: [`(\(?)\w+(?:(?: +|-)\w+)*(\)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/mR0fP5/1).

Answer (score 2):

You can split by:

```
/\s*(?<!\w(?=.\w))[\-[\]()]\s*/
```

#### Explanation:

1. The match is attempted against  the character class `[\-[\]()]` (matches any of those characters). You could also add any char you want to that character class.
2. It's using a negative lookbehind `(?<!\w)` for the condition: "not preceded by a word character".
3. And it also has a nested lookahead `(?=.\w)` that checks for: "if the first condition is met, it shouldn't be followed by any char -the one used to split- and a word character".
4. `\s*` at the beggining and the end is to trim whitespaces.

#### Code:

```
$input_line = "Some Words - Other Words (More Words) Dash-Binded-Word";
$result = preg_split("/\s*(?<!\w(?=.\w))[\-[\]()]\s*/", $input_line);
var_dump($result);
```

#### Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Some Words"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "Other Words"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "More Words"
  [3]=>
  string(16) "Dash-Binded-Word"
}
```

[Run this code here](http://rextester.com/CFVDU4303)

#### Capturing parens

As stated in another comment, if you want to also capture parentheses:

```
$result = preg_split("/\s*(?:(?<!\w)-(?!\w)|(\(.*?\)|\[.*?]))\s*/", $input_line, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting! So would I use preg_split with this regex to split the string into an array then?

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I have accepted @stribizhev answer as the code is shorter, it automatically trims unnecessary whitespace and doesn't create empty array values. Still, thank you so much, as this too solved my question. So I'll definitely up vote this. Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't know you wanted to trim whitespaces. New edit to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the input string to suit any particular exploding technique would be indirect and indicate that a suboptimal exploding technique is being used.

The truth is, your required logic can be boiled down to:  "**explode on each sequence of non-word characters that have a length of 2 or more**".  This is what that pattern looks like with `preg_split()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/M3spP))

```
$var = "Some Words - Other Words (More Words) Dash-Binded-Word";

var_export(preg_split('~\W{2,}~', $var));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Some Words',
  1 => 'Other Words',
  2 => 'More Words',
  3 => 'Dash-Binded-Word',
)
```

It doesn't get any simpler than that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (combination of str_replace and explode). It is not optimum but may work for this case:

```
$var = "Some Words - Other Words (More Words) Dash-Binded-Word";
$arr = Array(" - ", " (", ") ");
$var2 = str_replace($arr, "|", $var);
$final = explode('|', $var2);
var_dump($final);
```

Output:

> array(4) { [0]=> string(10) "Some Words" [1]=> string(11) "Other
>   Words" [2]=> string(10) "More Words" [3]=> string(16)
>   "Dash-Binded-Word" }

Answer (score -1):

```
$var = "Some Words - Other Words (More Words) Dash-Binded-Word";

$var=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z\-]/', ' ', $var);
$var=str_replace('-', ' ', $var); // Replaces all hyphens with spaces.
print_r (explode(" ",preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $var)));  //replaces all multiple spaces with one and explode creates array split where there is space
```

**OUTPUT :-**

```
Array ( [0] => Some [1] => Words [2] => Other [3] => Words [4] => More [5] => Words [6] => Dash [7] => Binded [8] => Word )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although this answer requires a few extra lines of code, I do think it could work. I'm a little bit worried about performance issues though, as it needs to index pretty large lists.
Also, this script will divide spaces as well right? So every word would get it's own part, whereas every part could potentially hold more words (like in the example).